# Spin coat of Graphene oxide on glass slides

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

I would like to spin coat Graphene oxide on the glass slides and intend to have a thickness of 100nm/0.1micrometre. May I know what is the amount of Graphene oxide to be poured onto the glass slides, spin time, spin speed and time for it to develop to obtain the optimized and desired thickness of 100nm?

Answer (score 4):

The procedure will vary with the size and shape of the glass, the concentration and viscosity of your graphene oxide dispersion, the solvent you're using, the wettability of your glass slide, and so on. You'll need to figure out the parameters yourself by varying the spinning conditions, measuring the resulting film thicknesses via profilometry/AFM/cross-sectional SEM, and then constructing spin curves ([examples](http://nanolithography.gatech.edu/zep520acurve.html)).